# Joomla Subsite Builder

Tags: domains, cms, joomla

I'm trying to build a New Joomla Site , which would be the Main Site and Users Registering to the site will be able to create their own Sub-sites. For. e.g. if main site is www.xyz.com then sub-sites would be usersname.xyz.com.

The steps in the Main Site that will help users to create thier own site are :-
1. Select user Registers
2. Select the Template from the list available , he can even customize or upload his own joomla template.
3. select the features that users can add to his site like blog, shopping site, Photo gallery , Music Gallery , Forums, etc.
4. Adds the url name of his choice for his sub -site.
5. Publish.

Can Some one help me on how this site can be build ?,
whether its pure customization or just having installed few components can do the job ?,
what about server space requirement ?
Can we build wizard like structure using any component for steps for the easy user interaction ?

Pls reply advice, suggestion will be rally appreciated.

Thanks,
Mukesh

Answer (score 1):

It looks like these people already do what you are proposing - http://www.lonex.com/content-management-system/joomla/

You have a big task on your hands with this one. Everything you described can be accomplished, but mostly using shell scripts. You would need to setup subdomains according to registered users then install Joomla on the subdomain then install components into Joomla, but I suggest focussing on getting the subdomain and Joomla installed. This will require access to certain files that you will probably not get access to on a shared hosting environment so you would need to look at dedicated host where you have full access to the server. It's also probably worth mentioning that you will require a database for every Joomla install, if you have many users then this can get very large!

To get you started have a look at this post - http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=53570 - about setting up subdomains. You could run these shell commands from php using shell_exec().

Then from there you are going to have to auto generate a database for each site, have a look at this tutorial - http://bash.cyberciti.biz/mysql/add-database-username-password-remote-host-access/

Now the hard part is installing Joomla. There are tools that already exist in cPanel for hosting accounts like Fantastico and SimpleScripts that give 1 click installs for common web applications. But this requires interaction, however these scripts illustrate that you will need to keep a check on the versions of Joomla you have installed and try and keep these up to date. So not only will you need to install Joomla, you will also need a script that can update each install of Joomla. Lots to think about here.

It might be worth having a look at these scripts which promise complete Joomla site installation. I haven't used them before though.

- http://www.howtoforge.net/forums/showthread.php?p=150321#post150321
- http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=8602
- http://joomla.astang.com/

Good luck, I think you will need it!